# Does using webkit this way make sense?

Tags: c++, browser, safari, webkit, cross-platform

I want to write a desktop application that looks as consistant as possible between Window and OSX. It will be doing some file system manipulation. I thought to write the UI in Html, CSS and JavaScript and extend Webkit to perform the tasks.

Can this be done using the Webkit project?

Comment: It should be possible but an ordinary web application could be a more optimal choice than embedding webkit.

Comment: Why use Webkit? Why not use just Qt? It does use the native API to draw all the buttons and windows.

Comment: @RedX, I have been closely looking at QT. I know that it can render widgets natively. However I wish to make the look as consistant as possible. In the same way that iTunes looks very consistant on both Windows and Mac. I'm good with HTML and CSS and have OOP programming exprience (not much with C++ though). So thats why I'm looking at alternative solutions such as webkit.